# What are the differences between SQL Native Client and SQL Native Client 10?

Tags: sql-server, upgrade, sqlncli

Can anyone direct me to a link or source that outlines either in general or in detail reasons to change your connection string from SQLNCLI to SQLNCLI10 when upgrading from SQL Server 2005 to 2008?

Outside of datatype issues, I am not seing any differences.  I just want to have as few steps as possible with minimal complication and if there are no performance gains, or missed functionality.   I just don't see the point in doing this step, at least at this moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below given aritcle on Microsoft SQLNCli team blog describes the differences between SQL Native Client and SQL Native Client 10.

[**Microsoft SQL Server Native Client and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlnativeclient/archive/2008/02/27/microsoft-sql-server-native-client-and-microsoft-sql-server-2008-native-client.aspx)